# React-Router-Redux Replace

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

In React-Router-Redux, it is very easy to push to history from the actions creators.

Ex.

```
export function setPage(page) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(push(page));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to `replace` state instead of push, I get "Uncaught TypeError: replace is not a function".

Am I doing something wrong here? As with push, I imported replace like so `import { push, replace } from 'react-router-redux';`